# How to improve performance for lighting calculations in a phong lighting model

Tags: opengl, shader, lighting

I've successfully implemented a phong lighting model doing all the lighting calculations in a fragment shader - it looks smooth, but that's causes some performance issues if having a lot of objects in a scene. One solution is to do all the calculations in a vertex shader - but because of the linear interpolation from the vertex shader, the result is not accuracy and smooth. So how to make objects look pretty and smooth without sacrificing the performance ??
vertex shader

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

out vec4 fragPosition;
out vec3 vNormal;

out vec3 LightPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    fragPosition = view * model * position;
    vNormal = normalize(mat3(normalMatrix) * normal);
    LightPosition = vec3(view * vec4(lightPosition, 1.0));
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 450 core

struct Material
{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 LightPosition;
in vec4 fragPosition;
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    vec3 norm = vNormal;
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(LightPosition - vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);

    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;
    vec3 diffuse = (material.diffuse * max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0)) * light.diffuse;
    vec3 specular = (material.specular * pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), material.shininess)) * light.specular;

    color = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1.0f);    //  phong lighting model
}
```

results this
[image]

so when calculate the light in a vertex shader

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;

struct Material
{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

uniform mat4 mvp;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 normalMatrix;
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

out vec3 finalColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = mvp * position;
    vec4 fragPosition = view * model * position;
    vec3 vNormal = normalize(mat3(normalMatrix) * normal);
    vec3 _lightPosition = vec3(view * vec4(lightPosition, 1.0));

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(_lightPosition - vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, vNormal);

    vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;
    vec3 diffuse = (material.diffuse * max(dot(vNormal, lightDir), 0.0)) * light.diffuse;
    vec3 specular = (material.specular * pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), material.shininess)) * light.specular;
    finalColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
}
```

and corresponding fragment

```
#version 450 core

in vec3 finalColor;
out vec4 color;

void main() {


    color = vec4(finalColor, 1.0f);    //  phong lighting model
}
```

output is this:
[image]

Comment: Without seeing your actual fragment shader code we can't give you any advice on where the bottlenecks are. For all we know you could be doing things that trash performance but would be easily rewritten into something very GPU friendly and performant. But without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @datenwolf added code of both fragment and vertex shaders with their results.

Answer (score 3):

The specific reason it's called "Phong" shading is that it's done on the fragment shader; Gouraud shading is the same thing, but done on the vertex shader (and is what you've *actually* done in your example), and is the main way to improve performance, but at the expense of visual accuracy.

In a general sense, therefore, **the only way you can change the algorithm is to sacrifice Phong's accuracy for Gouraud's speed, or vise-versa**.

Now, depending on the specifics of your code, there may be optimizations that can be done here & there to speed things up marginally. As an example, since the objects you're rendering are cubes (and thus have sharp, flat edges), you might be able to calculate the normal + position of the fragment in the vertex shader and pass it along to the fragment shader, which may save some calculations there. There may also be some other ways to improve the detailed performance of your algorithm.

But in general, there aren't significant changes that can be made to the overall algorithm that would allow you to escape that "Performance vs Appearance" decision.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious optimization is moving everything into the vertex shader that is linear (i.e. its evaluation doesn't include powers or trigonometrics). That is because chains of linear mappings can be reduced to a single linear map, or decomposed into several.

In your case the following calculations in the fragment shader are linear, except for the `normalize` part (contains a pow(x,0.5)) and thus could be moved into the vertex shader.

```
vec3 norm = vNormal;
vec3 lightDir = normalize(LightPosition - vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
vec3 viewDir = normalize(-vec3(fragPosition.xyz));
vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, norm);
```

But even with normalization it interpolates linearly (exercise for the reader: why? Hint: how does the length of a vector change under linear interpolation?). So moving that already greatly reduces the complexity of the fragment shader.

Then there is the issue of uniform constant expresions, for example this one:

```
vec3 ambient = material.ambient * light.ambient;
```

Now depending on the quality of the GLSL compiler and/or the capabilities of the hardware regarding uniform buffer blocks this expression might be replaced by a single uniform constant on the driver level. However it's always a good idea to have such uniform values explicitly evaluated ex-shader. Both your diffuse and specular terms contain similar uniform constant sub terms. So it's probably a good idea to coalesce those into a single `LightMaterial` struct and evaluate on the CPU side.

`dot` (which is *cos(angle)·length(a)·length(b)*, *length(v)=sqrt(dot(a,a))*) and `pow` are nonlinear and having those two in the fragment shader is what differentiates Phong from Gourad.

Comment: tried your improvements and there wasn't any significant difference's. Also the shinines scattered a little bit.